# Shader is not working correctly / set(material.[]) is buggy

Tags: display, png, sql-view, cityengine, texture

Concider this first Example:

My CGA File:

```
const dryWallCol            = "Walltexture1/Drywall4.png"


Lot -->                 primitiveCube(20,20,20)                         
                        
                        setupProjection( 0 , sayit , 37.5 , 25)
                        projectUV(0)
                        set(material.colormap, dryWallCol)
```

My Texture is mostly white, but in the viewport and later on export to Unreal the texture is a dark Gray. Why?

[image: myTexture]

[image: output in Cityengine]

Concider the second Example:

MyCGAFile:

```
const leer              = ""
const sayit             = "scope.xy"
const dryWallCol            = "Walltexture1/Drywall4.png"
const dryWallNor            = "Walltexture1/Drywall4Normal.png"
const dryWallHei            = "Walltexture1/Drywall4Height.png"

Lot -->                 primitiveCube(20,20,20)

                        setupProjection( 0 , sayit , 37.5 , 25)
                        projectUV(0)
                        set(material.colormap, dryWallCol)
                        
                        setupProjection( 1 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(1)
                        set(material.bumpmap, dryWallHei)
                        
                        setupProjection( 2 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(2)
                        set(material.dirtmap, leer)

                        setupProjection( 3 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(3)                        
                        set(material.specularmap, leer)
                        
                        setupProjection( 4 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(4)
                        set(material.opacitymap, leer)
                        
                        setupProjection( 5 , sayit , 37.5 , 25)
                        projectUV(5)
                        set(material.normalmap, dryWallNor)

                        setupProjection( 6 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(6)                        
                        set(material.emissivemap, leer)
                        
                        setupProjection( 7 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(7)
                        set(material.occlusionmap, leer)
                        
                        setupProjection( 8 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(8)
                        set(material.roughnessmap, leer)
                        
                        setupProjection( 9 , sayit , 37.5 , 25) 
                        projectUV(9)
                        set(material.metallicmap, leer)
```

I set every other material to empty, so I can check if they are the problem - they are not. I also checked the Textures several times, the color profiles are allright etc. but as soon as I try to use either of them, the builtin UnknownTexture.png plasters over everything. Why?

[image: mynormalTexture]

[image: height/bumpTexture]

[image]

Concider my third example:

imagine the code from before, but right after the primitive cube there is

```
set(material.shader, "CityEnginePBRShader")
```

This only solves the problem in the first example if you set the bumpmap.
But normalmap still can't be used because the builtin UnknownTexture.png plasters over everything again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Example**

It looks like that part of the cube is darker in CityEngine because of the steep angle of the sun? If you rotate the cube it will probably change the dark parts of the cube accordingly. Also it looks like your UVs are not correctly setup. To set them up for all faces of the cube you can use this CGA snippet:

```
    comp(f) { 
        all : 
            setupProjection(0, scope.xy, 20, 20) 
            projectUV(0)
            set(material.colormap, "wall.png")
            Wall.
        }
```

The component split (https://doc.arcgis.com/en/cityengine/latest/cga/cga-comp.htm) will align the scope appropriately.

I exported a similar cube to Unreal and it looks like this:

[image: Cube Shading]

It might be an issue with the automatic exposure setup in Unreal which could make it look too dark. You can quickly check that in the View Mode settings here by changing the EV100 parameter:

[image: ViewModeSettings]

Or using a Post Processing Volume (https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/AutomaticExposure/index.html) in Game.

**Second example**

You don't need to setup multiple UV channels if they use the same projection. Eg something like this works for me:

```
@StartRule
start -->
    extrude(30)
    comp(f) { 
        all : 
            setupProjection(0, scope.xy, 20, 20) 
            projectUV(0)
            set(material.colormap, "wall.png")
            set(material.normalmap, "wallNormal.png")
            set(material.bumpmap, "wallHeight.png")
            Wall.
        }
```

The `Unkonwn Texture` only appears if your texture can not be found. Are you sure the textures are in the `assets` folder of your project? Eg. `assets/Walltexture1/Drywall4.png`. In my example I just copied the textures into the assets folder and renamed them to `wall.png`, `wallNormal.png` and `wallHeight.png` etc.

**Third example**

> imagine the code from before, but right after the primitive cube there is
> `set(material.shader, "CityEnginePBRShader")`

The reason why this solves the issue is that the Unreal Exporter with PBR materials does not support bump maps and ignores them. But again it is probably an issue with texture paths as mentioned before.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: It is embarassing to say, but I misspelled the name in the pictures of the asset-path.
But since the post helps me understand texturing much better than before I thank you a lot for the contribution!